# Scala - easiest and fastest way to encode and decode Json

Tags: json, scala

I am very much confused with the different versions of Scala available and the different versions of Json libraries. I am using Scala version 2.9.2. What is the best library available for this version to encode and decode Json?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling) framework. It's very easy to setup and works perfectly with case class.

Comment: will it work for Scala 2.9.2?

Comment: No, this library requires 2.10.2

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is going to be matter of opinion, but [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) is an excellent library which when used together with [JacksMapper](https://github.com/wg/jacks) as a wrapper, makes it pleasant for a Scala usage.

Serializing to JSON becomes as simple as

```
val json = JacksMapper.writeValueAsString[MyClass](instance)
```

... and deserializing

```
val instance = JacksMapper.readValue[MyClass](json)
```

Jacks seems to be available for 2.9.2 (Maven artifact below) and working with Jackson 2.2.2

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacks_2.9.2</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I got the errors 1)error while loading JavaType, Missing dependency 'class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.ResolvedType', required by C:\Users\YasHo\Downloads\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar(com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType.class)    2)error while loading ObjectMapper, Missing dependency 'class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec', required by C:\Users\YasHo\Downloads\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar(com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.class)                   after adding the jars

Comment: You need jackson-databind, jackson-annotations and jackson-core

Comment: Has anybody seen [this article that adds string interpolation](http://mandubian.com/2013/07/04/json-interpolation-pattern-matching/)?  I just thought that was a cool way to deal simplify the syntax. (still uses Jackson behind the scenes)

Comment: @MichaelTiller Nice! I use the (very basic) library from json.org to do the same thing. This definitely looks better and more scala-ish

Comment: @BGR It is taiking more than 10 seconds to parse a Map with 10000 entries!